# Transfer ownership of specific mapped array to a different address

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping

I have this contract with a mapped array of the struct Item linked to a specific address. I want to transfer a specific array in Item[] to a different owner/address. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
contract Linked {

    struct Item {
        address owner;
        string qrcode;
    }
    
    mapping(address => Item[]) public userItems;

    function addItem(string memory _qrcode) public {
        Item memory item = Item(msg.sender, _qrcode);
        userItems[msg.sender].push(item);
        items.push(item);
    }

    function transfer(string memory _qrcode, address _newOwner) public returns (bool success){
       //find the row with the qrcode and transfer to another owner
    }
 }
```

Comment: Define "ownership".

Comment: The address that a specific row inside Item[] is linked to.

Comment: Better use `mapping(address => mapping(address => string)) userItems;` and `mapping(address => address[]) userItemKeys;` for your data structure.